# How to find the length of paralell line crossing the centroid of triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given:

```
Triangle ABC
AB = 6
MN(M belongs to AC, N belongs to BC) is parallel to AB and it's crossing the centroid of the triangle.

Find the length of MN
```

I'm totally stuck on this one, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT :

The centroid divides each of the medians in the ratio $2:1$. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_triangle_and_tetrahedron))

So, we have $CM:MA=2:1$.

Comment: This is perfectly clear for me. However I don't understand what to do with it. Since I'm searching MN, how is AC related to it, also I know AB and i have no idea what is the length of AC

Comment: @Planet_Earth: Since $MN$ is parallel to $AB$, we know that $\triangle{CMN}$ and $\triangle{CAB}$ are similar. So, we have $MN:AB=CM:CA$, i.e. $MN:6=2:3$.

Comment: Got it, so simple!